# Wordpress distributed development and database management

Tags: database, wordpress

I am looking for a way to handle a distributed development for Wordpress. For the moment I set up a shared git repository on which I have all the code of the website versioned. The problem I'm having regards how to handle the database. Clearly I need our site running while we (me and other developers) improve the website locally. This means that the user of the website (which is not up yet) will be able to modify our database (user registration, etc.) while we are working on the development of the site locally, using a dump of the database.
What I am trying to understand is the best practice to handle a shared development like this,  while the site is running and thus the database can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you develop, theme or plugins but with WordPress the change in the database should not have an effect on your development, unless you set something up where the user can create new custom posts, with that I mean a new "custom post" not a new post based on a custom post, which could potentially change the behavior of what you are developing.

If the user runs into something odd because of what they did, well that's called bug fixing, the good news is that you can just export and import the database to fix whatever they run into.

Answer (score 0):

Database data changes isn't your problem (dump exchange, if needed, solve most)

Changes of structure are another big question, you can try to see (for **brain-powered solution**) on [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/overview)